# Find last document of an array of documents with different values with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of values that I use to query some data. I need to get the last document of each value in the array. I prefer to explain with some code:

Schema:

```
const quizResultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  answeredByUser: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  levelAnswered: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'QuizLevel' },
});
```

controller:

```
QuizResult.find(
    {
      levelAnswered: { $in: levelIds },
      answeredByUser: result.applicant._id,
    },
    {},
    { sort: { created: -1 } }
  )
```

`levelIds` is an array of Ids and I use it to return an array of documents. The problem is that I'm getting all the documents for each Id in the array sorted by date. What I need is to get the last created document and not all the documents for each Id.

How can I do that? Is it possible to do it just with Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this by grouping and using [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            levelAnswered: { $in: levelIds },
            answeredByUser: result.applicant._id,
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$levelAnswered",
            last: {$last: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$last"
        }
    }
])
```